# sum of xor of all subarray

Tags: algorithm, xor, bitset

In the implementation of [the approach described below](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-of-xor-of-all-subarrays/) I am not getting how these two loops are considering which part of the test case,I mean how these two loops covering all possibilities . Please help

problem link [xor subbarray](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-of-xor-of-all-subarrays/)

```
// loop to calculate initial 
// value of c_odd 
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { 
    if ((arr[j] & (1 << i)) > 0) 
        odd = (!odd); 
    if (odd) 
        c_odd++; 
}
```

and this one

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { 
    sum += (mul * c_odd); 

    if ((arr[j] & (1 << i)) > 0) 
        c_odd = (n - j - c_odd); 
}
```

Description from Geeks for Geeks:

Best solution : For the sake of better understanding, let’s assume any bit of an element is represented by the variable ‘i’ and the variable ‘sum’ is used to store the final sum.

The idea here is, we will try to find the number of XOR values with ith bit set. Let us suppose, there are ‘Si‘ number of sub-arrays with ith bit set. For, ith bit, sum can be updated as sum += (2i * S) .

So, the question is how to implement the above idea?

We will break the task to multiple steps. At each step, we will try to find the number of XOR values with ith bit set.
Now, we will break each step to sub-steps. In each sub-step, we will try to find the number of sub-arrays staring from an index ‘j'(where j varies between 0 to n – 1) with ith bit set in there XOR value. For, ith bit is to be set, odd number of elements of the sub-array should have there ith bit set.
For all the bits, in a variable c_odd, we will store the count of the number of sub-arrays starting from j = 0 with ith bit set in odd number of elements. Then, we will iterate through all the elements of the array updating the value of c_odd when needed. If we reach an element ‘j’ with ith bit set, we will update c_odd as c_odd = (n – j – c_odd). Its because, since we encountered a set bit, number of sub-arrays with even number of elements with ith bit set will switch to number of sub-arrays with odd number of elements with ith bit set.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of where a more careful, descriptive formulation of the procedure could have made it easier to understand, as well as more correct.

We are looking at each bit separately.

Let's consider the first loop: it's counting how many subarrays *that start at index 0* have an odd count of the current bit set. (It seems clear to see how this count is achieved but feel free to ask.)

Now, in the second loop, we can use this information (and update it) as all subarrays that *start we we are currently* (rather than start at index 0) *and end anywhere later*. Let's say the initial count was 2, and `n = 10`, and the current bit is set on elements at indexes 4 and 6 in the array.

Now, on each iteration, we are marking the left/low bound of the subarrays we are counting. We already know there are 2 subarrays that started at index 0 and ended "somewhere later." But since there is no instance of this bit set until index 4, we can say that this count is true also for low-bound 1, 2, 3 and 4: there's 2 counts of subarrays starting at those indexes and ending "somewhere later."

When we reach index 4 is where the magic happens and we need to update our count. If until now, there were 2 subarrays with an odd count of bit `i` set starting here and ending "later," there were `10 - here - 2` subarrays with an *even* count of bit `i` set starting here and ending "later" (A[4..4], A[4..5], ... A[4..9] but excluding A[4..4] and A[4..5] that only have one count of bit `i` set).

When we reach index 4, we recalculate the count of *subarrays with an odd count of bit `i` set starting here and ending "somewhere later"* as `n - j - current_odd_count` since we passed an instance of the set bit and we can flip all the subarrays that previously had an even count to our new measure.

Comment: I am very much thankful sir you helped me But  I am not getting the second loop explanation can you please give an example with a array.

Comment: like I have a[ ]={3,8,13,11,3,5} after coming out of first loop it will have c_odd=4 and then I entered to the second loop and again compute  c_odd = 6-0-4
 now c_odd=2 now this 2  means there will be two sub arrays  with odd no of current bit But I am not getting the intuition Please help with an array example.

Please help sir  I am trying this question from 3 days and frustrated now  but  I am not getting I have now very silly doubt that I can get easily with example .

Comment: @akacodes121 I gave an example in my answer that many arrays could fit. Try to follow the logic for this one: {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 ,0} (there is only one bit to consider). Think about when and how `c_odd` is updated. That's what my answer explains.